# Woocommerce product api v3 not accept urls images for 9191 port. Only 8080

Tags: api, rest, woocommerce

My POST request (JSON to create PRODUCT IN WOOCOMMERCE API V3) fail for images.

I have the same image exposed to the internet through 2 different ports. https fails too

----------------  Fail:  not Works for 9191 or other port --------------------------------

```
{
          "src": "http://190.64.76.10:9191/img/logo.png"
}
```

Error

```
{
"code": "woocommerce_product_image_upload_error",
"message": "Error getting remote image http://190.64.76.10:9191/img/logo.png. A valid URL has not been provided",
"data": {
    "status": 400
}
```

}

----------------   Works fine with 8080 port --------------------------------

```
{
          "src": "http://190.64.76.10:8080/img/logo.png"
}
```

**Any ideas ?????**

Answer (score 3):

Internally, the URL is validated by calling [`wp_http_validate_url`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_http_validate_url/). Among other rules, it checks whether the port is one of 80, 443 or 8080:

```php
$port = $parsed_url['port'];
if ( 80 === $port || 443 === $port || 8080 === $port ) {
    return $url;
}
```

You can see the relevant part of the code on GitHub [here](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/e26394bb2dd50faa1e425555d29bd088d57b369b/src/wp-includes/http.php#L583). There is also an issue where some had the same problem, which you can find [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/16702).

So, bottom line, by default you just cannot use any other port than 80, 443 or 8080. There is no way to change that other than disabling the URL validation in WordPress, which is probably not a good idea security-wise.

But if you really need it, you can do it by adding the following code in a plugin or theme in your WordPress installation:

```php
add_filter('http_request_args', function ($args, $url) {
  $args['reject_unsafe_urls'] = false;
  return $args;
}, 50, 2);
```

Comment: I edit this file .../rest-api/class-wp-rest-request.php. works fine for 9191 port now.